# lambda function in class header

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to create nan value for integer. the design i am thinking about is the following.
I need to create and isnan lambda function in the class definition header but it returns an error

```
import numpy as np

class Integer(object):
    type = int
    nan  = -1
    isnan = lambda val: val==-1
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return cls.type(value)  

class Float(object):
    type = float
    isnan = lambda val: np.isnan(val)
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return cls.type(value)
```

but it returns an error

```
>> Integer.isnan(1)
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>>TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with Integer instance as first argument (got     int instance instead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `isnan` functions are being treated as instance methods by Python. Even though you're using them "unbound", Python 2 still does a type check to ensure that the first argument to a method is an instance of the class (e.g. `self`). In Python 3, unbound methods have been discarded, and your code would work just fine.

You can work around this by passing the lambda function through `staticmethod`:

```
isnan = staticmethod(lambda val: val == -1)
```

Or you could use a regular function definition, with `staticmethod` as a decorator:

```
@staticmethod
def isnan(value):
    return val == -1
```

Note that if you made your classes inherit from their `type` value, you could call `isnan` as an actual instance method:

```
class Integer(int):
    # no __new__ needed
    def isnan(self):
        return self == -1
```

This would let you call `Integer(5).isnan()`, rather than what you do in your current code.

One final suggestion: Don't use `type` as a variable name, since it is already the name of the built-in `type` class. It's not as bad using it as a class attribute as it would be as a variable (where it would shadow the built-in), but it can still be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it a static method. Two choices:

```
class Integer(object):
    type = int 
    nan  = -1

    @staticmethod
    def isnan(v): 
        return v == -1

    isnan_lambda = staticmethod(lambda v: v == -1)

    def __new__(cls, value):
        return cls.type(value) 

print Integer.isnan(5)
print Integer.isnan(5)
```